# Error while installing MITMF unoknow python in Kali Linux 2021.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, github

```
─$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting git+https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Cloning https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue to /tmp/pip-req-build-dje0np6n
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue /tmp/pip-req-build-dje0np6n
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pyinotify in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.9.6)
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (3.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: netaddr in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scapy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: dnslib in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.9.16)
Requirement already satisfied: Twisted in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (4.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (2021.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ipy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: user_agents in /home/jatin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (21.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: service_identity in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: configobj in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (5.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 18)) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 19)) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 20)) (4.10.0)
Collecting capstone
  Using cached capstone-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-magic in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 22)) (0.4.24)
Collecting msgpack-python
  Using cached msgpack_python-0.5.6-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 24)) (2.25.1)
Collecting pypcap
  Using cached pypcap-1.2.3.tar.gz (136 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 26)) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ua-parser>=0.10.0 in /home/jatin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from user_agents->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (0.10.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: NetfilterQueue, pypcap
  Building wheel for NetfilterQueue (PEP 517) ... done
  Created wheel for NetfilterQueue: filename=NetfilterQueue-0.9.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=202311 sha256=7fe86a37ff9c4a563edd2a4ba09d35f1b861ffecd2095ca82b0f27cdf1b6739a
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-40iytwga/wheels/4b/6f/d6/b2a045d4178b9135d3e6c578309c6847f4a9e40783183cf202
  Building wheel for pypcap (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5dh8kl6w/pypcap_21a63e1bf8744f74b7419ba412232794/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5dh8kl6w/pypcap_21a63e1bf8744f74b7419ba412232794/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-nbx7uooe                                   
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5dh8kl6w/pypcap_21a63e1bf8744f74b7419ba412232794/
```

Comment: https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf : "This project is no longer being updated ..... Since then (~2015) many other tools have been created ....... you should probably be using Bettercap as it is far more feature complete ..." . Note: MITMF is a python2.7 program.

Comment: `pycap` is python2 . `pycap3` is the python3 version https://pypi.org/project/pypcap3/